# How to Install evolution-alarm-notify on ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: software-installation

I have searched everywhere but i can't find how to install, kindly guide me through. Thank you. in addition i also want to set up the alarm notifier too. Thanks

Comment: You probably need to install the evolution package

Comment: any link please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install evolution with the command `sudo apt install evolution` .

In ubuntu, most software can be installed from the official repositories, without manually downloading installers from the internet.